# Problem With Updating Database through DataAdapters/datasets in C#/Visual studio

Tags: c#, database, dataset, database-connection

I try updating my database after updating the dataset, but evenafter calling the data adapter's update function the underlying database doesn't change. I used SqlCommandBuilder and it still wouldn't update. Once I have the GUI open I can submit and search for values in my dataset but once I close it then re run it, all the changes are gone. Help?

```
    Code:

        //in my form load event
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        ds1 = new DataSet();
        ds2 = new DataSet();

        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

        con.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Database Open.");

        string sql = "SELECT * From tblPurchases";
        da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);

        string cust = "SELECT * From tblCustomers";
        da2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cust, con);

        da.Fill(ds1, "Purchases");
        numOfRecords = ds1.Tables["Purchases"].Rows.Count;

        da2.Fill(ds2, "Customers");
        numOfCustomers = ds2.Tables["Customers"].Rows.Count;

        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Database Closed.");

    Code:
            //in my submit button click event

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb;
            cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da);

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb2;
            cb2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da2);

            DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Purchases"].NewRow();
            DataRow dRow2 = ds2.Tables["Customers"].NewRow();

            //dRow updating happens here

            ds1.Tables["Purchases"].Rows.Add(dRow);
            ds2.Tables["Customers"].Rows.Add(dRow2);

            da.Update(ds1, "Purchases");
            da2.Update(ds2, "Customers");
```

That's it. There are no error messages, it's just that even with that, the underlying database doesn't update and the updates only go as far as the dataset.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! Edit your question to include relevant code and actual error messages to help illustrate.

Comment: I've updated the post with relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` method returns an integer with the number of rows successfully updated. Consider loading that value into a variable to determine if any rows were reported as updated.

The [SqlCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx) likely needs its `.GetUpdateCommand()` method called.  `GetUpdateCommand` [gets the automatically generated SqlCommand object required to perform updates on the database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfbedfwf.aspx).

```
cb.GetUpdateCommand();
cb2.GetUpdateCommand();

da.Update(ds1, "Purchases");
da2.Update(ds2, "Customers");
```

Consider running SQL Server Profiler against your server to determine the TSQL statements that are being generated by the SqlCommand. This will be extremely helpful in determining if the database and statements are as you expect.

Comment: I did the cb.GetUpdateCommand(); it did nothing. The database is still null. I also returned the integer value, it returned 1, which is correct, but when I checked the database everything was still null. This problem has stumped me for a week now, and the working prototype submission is soon so I decided to ask here.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. The connection is set such that i can save and update values to the database, but everytime i close the program then run it again, it refreshes the database so that all the recent data is lost. I don't know how to fix it though.

Answer (score 0):

All that you need to do is to change the

```
con.ConnectionString = 
`"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

that is going to be generated at run time to the real one, like changing `|DataDirectory|` to the real path.  Example: `c:\\blablablabla`.